# How to approach for this kind of changing mod_rewrite rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of mod_write rules

```
RewriteRule ^connect$ connect.php
RewriteRule ^stuff$ stuff.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
```

..and so on.

On this app, a user can create their own page and get a fancy url, e.g:

```
www.url.com/customnamehere
```

If I were to have a rewrite_rule for this it would look something like:

```
RewriteRule ^customenamehere$ page.php?name=customnamehere
```

But of course, I'm not going to manually create a rewrite_rule for each one of these custom pages because there could be many of them.. maybe thousands, which would make for a very huge and slow performing htaccess file.

Which brings me to my obstacle: how to have it so that if none of the initial 'fixed' rewrite_rules are matched, then to load the user page? I thought perhaps I could have all my regular rules at the start, and then at the end of all the other rules, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?name=$1
```

I was wrong.

How would you approach this? A database of all these custom names using apaches external rewrite engine, then included into the htaccess file somehow perhaps (this seems slow with a large db)? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a condition so that the rule that routes to `page.php` doesn't get applied when one of the rules before it has been applied. You can do this by checking the `-f` and `-d` flags. You should also place `L` flags at the end of your other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^connect$ connect.php [L]
RewriteRule ^stuff$ stuff.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?source_url=$1
```

You can also check for php there if you want, since you probably don't want custom names to end with ".php":

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?source_url=$1
```

Though the `-f` and `-d` checks are probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Can the RewriteCond to check for PHP be used as well as the -f and -d checks?